# Update query with one unique value other one with varying values

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, sql-server, sql-server-ce

Want a query possibly a single query for the below conditions

[image: Sample Table]

1. To be updated value of column 3 and 4 is same for all 4 R2IGTNo column
2. Sometimes the blend will be up to 3 only, 4th row may not come
3. In C# application user will update for the first row (blend 1), other values have to be updated automatically since the values are the same.

I need a query, expert please help with this... Thanks

Comment: Thanks for guiding. I feel this site is too sensitive to the formats. Nowadays everything is automated.

Comment: Is there any common identifier for the 4 rows. If yes, you could update based on that identifier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

User picks row 1, this means your C# can know "Lot21009BB1C3" (putting text instead of image would have let me copy it, btw) but you write like the c# app doesn't know any other row..

Which means you can run a query:

```
UPDATE t SET HtrOnBy = @HtrOnBy, ChtrOnRemark = @ChtrOnRemark
WHERE R2IGTNo LIKE @R2IGTNo
```

And your c# shall put the following values:

```
@HtrOnBy = "Whatever it knows the first row HtrOnBy is"
@ChtrOnRemark = "Whatever it knows the first row ChtrOnRemark is"
@R2IGTNo = firstRowR2IGTNo.Remove(9) + "%"
```

We take the first 9 characters of R2IGTNo and add a percent. SQL will update all the rows that start with those, doesn't matter if it's 3 or 4 etc

If the number of chars varies, then you will have to get more smart about how you do your substring, such as looking for the first character after the numbers (eg regex)

Comment: oh Thank you Certainly it will work. i pulled my hair written in Sql Query as below and its perfectly working. still your answer will do the same so I mark yours as Answer.  meantime my answered Query is :  `UPDATE [tbl1RMWeighingDetails] SET  [ChtrOnRemark] = @ChtrOnRemark, [HtrOnBy] = @HtrOnBy WHERE  [R2IGTNo] like  LEFT(@original_R2IGTNo, PATINDEX('%B1%', @original_R2IGTNo))+'%'  `

Comment: Yep, it looks like it'll work too.. don't be afraid to do some processing of data in C# , eg `r2string.Remove(r2stribg.IndexOf("B1"))` instead of PATINDEX for example

Comment: Yes, 
 Thank you @Caius Jard this idea will help me.